# php array problems with foreach statement (code-igniter)

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, drop-down-menu, foreach

Currently I have

```
private function getYears()
{
    return array('Test1', 'Test2', 'Test3', 'Test4');
}
```

in the index:

```
$years = $this->getYears();
```

and in the view

```
<select>
    <?php foreach ($years as $row):?>
        <option><?=$row?></option>
    <?php endforeach;?>
</select>
```

The select box doesn't get filled ?

How can I fix this ?

**[edit]**

So far I noticed that the $years is empty and the getYears is not being called..  no idea why yet..

Comment: why `$pages` and not `years` ?

Comment: try `var_dump($years);` to see what inside `$years`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<select>
    <?php foreach ($years as $row):?>
        <option><?=$row?></option>
    <?php endforeach;?>
</select>
```

Comment: Yes this was a typo.. now I have it set to years and it actually doesn't fill the select box at all... so what am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what you're iterating over.

You've passed the values to `$years`, yet you're iterating over `$pages`. Is that a typo?

In any case, you're iterating over an array of arrays. Do a var_dump on the `$row` variable and check what you're actually iterating over.

Answer (score 0):

Not advisable iteration, it is better to iterate in the controller and use view to create get html tags and just pass the data to the main view .